# Add Facebook Shimmer on multiple UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, loading

I am trying to add Facebook Shimmer on UICollectionViewCell which has multiple UIViews.

For **one UIView**, it's working fine with below code:

```
let shimmeringView = FBShimmeringView(frame: imageView.frame)
shimmeringView.contentView = imageView
backgroundView.addSubview(shimmeringView)
shimmeringView.isShimmering = true
```

Where `backgroundView` is the view in which I have all the subviews such as `imageView`, `labelView` and others.

While I am trying to add multiple views then first view is getting correct frame but other views' widths are becoming zero. I'm adding this code inside `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`.

```
let shimmeringView = FBShimmeringView(frame: imageView.frame)
shimmeringView.contentView = imageView
backgroundView.addSubview(shimmeringView)
shimmeringView.isShimmering = true

let shimmeringView = FBShimmeringView(frame: labelView.frame)
shimmeringView.contentView = labelView
backgroundView.addSubview(shimmeringView)
shimmeringView.isShimmering = true
```

Can anyone tell me if it's the **correct way to implement Facebook Shimmer for multiple `UIView`s** or Where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are many ways to implement `FBShimmeringView`, it's a matter of preferences. So in my case, I prefer the easiest way (according to me).

What I do in my `tableViewCell` that has of course multiple views such as `imageView` and `labels`, just like yours, is that I have multiple `UIView` gray color, placed on top of each views in my cell.

Then I only have ONE instance of `FBShimmeringView` added to my cell.

Here are some more details about what I practice for using `FBShimmeringView`.

*Take note that I use `SnapKit` to layout my views programmatically.

1. I have a property in my cell called `isLoading` like so, which determines if the gray colored views should be shown or now. If shown, of course turn on shimmering:

   ```
   public var serviceIsLoading: Bool = false {
       didSet {
           _ = self.view_Placeholders.map { $0.isHidden = !self.serviceIsLoading }
           self.view_Shimmering.isHidden = !self.serviceIsLoading
           self.view_Shimmering.isShimmering = self.serviceIsLoading
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then I add a white view to my cell after adding all the subviews to the cell:

   ```
   // Place the FBShimmeringView
   // Try to add a dummy view
   let dummyView = UIView()
   dummyView.backgroundColor = .white
   self.addSubview(dummyView)
   dummyView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
       make.edges.equalToSuperview()
   }
   ```
3. Add the ShimerringView to the cell as well:

   ```
   self.addSubview(self.view_Shimmering)
   self.view_Shimmering.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
       make.height.width.equalToSuperview()
       make.center.equalToSuperview()
   }
   ```
4. Finally, make the dummyView as the contentView of the cell:

   ```
   self.view_Shimmering.contentView = dummyView
   ```

My screen would look like this. Also remember to disable interaction in your `tableView`.

This looks cool to me when it shimmers, just one shimerring view.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Below extension is working fine.

```
extension UIView {
    func startShimmeringViewAnimation() {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        let gradientColorOne = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let gradientColorTwo = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        gradientLayer.colors = [gradientColorOne, gradientColorTwo, gradientColorOne]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        animation.fromValue = [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0]
        animation.toValue = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        animation.duration = 1.25
        gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
    }
}
```

In UITableViewCell class, we need to add the Shimmer for each views.

```
class UAShimmerCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var thumbNailView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label1View: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2View: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        thumbNailView.startShimmeringViewAnimation()
        label1View.startShimmeringViewAnimation()
        label2View.startShimmeringViewAnimation()
    }
}
```

Comment: How to stop the shimmer effect?

Comment: just hide the views