# iOS Swift 4 before loading content

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, preload

I build chat app using Firebase API right now. I wan't to make preload icons like on facebook screenshot. I thought i can create empty images and label fields and fill them after content loaded, but i don't know how to check if all data loaded from DB. How i can do that in correct way?

[image]

This is where i want to place objects

[image]

Comment: Actually, this is template image(gif image) as like used here. https://codeburst.io/achieve-skeleton-loading-with-react-a12404678030 These templates used in tableview before loading datasource. Idea behind this : Instead of showing progress indicator, temporarily showing 3 cell with animated images alone(normally using gif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install [ListPlaceholder](https://github.com/malkouz/ListPlaceholder)  this lib.
2. import ListPlaceholder

To show the loader, start showing this from start

```
tableView.showLoader()
```

To hide the loader, end showing after data has been loaded

```
 tableView.hideLoader()
```

Please refer this may get help.
https://github.com/malkouz/ListPlaceholder

Comment: tableview and collection view in not working this library.

Answer (score 1):

**To hide the loading use tableView.hideLoader()**

[ListPlaceholder](https://github.com/malkouz/ListPlaceholder) helped me to resolve the issue. All that I did was added the ListLoader.swift file to my project and added tableView.reloadData(), tableView.showLoader() in viewDidAppear in the tableView where I wanted to show loading.
( ListLoader.swif uses visibleCells to determine the number of rows on which the loading should be shown. In my applications, visibleCell's count was incorrect on calling tableView.showLoader() method in viewDidLoad )

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has it's own library called [Shimmer](https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer). To use this on tableview, you can follow [this StackOverflow question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251056/add-facebook-shimmer-on-multiple-uiviews).

You'll just have to create the `UIView` you want to animate and above that you'll have to add your `FBShimmeringView`. At the end set `shimmeringView.shimmering = true` to start shimmering